# using 'don't care' syntax possible in rspec?

Tags: rspec

This test checks whether a tic-tac-toe board created by the `generate_game` method indeed has three subarrays of three values each. But can I express this in a single line such as I tried to do in the commented line?

```
it "should have three rows of three squares each" do
   #   expect([[_,_,_], [_,_,_], [_,_,_]] === generate_game).to_be true
      game = generate_game
      expect(game.length).to eq(3)
      0.upto(2) do |num|
        expect(game[num].length).to eq(3)
      end
    end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Do you want to make sure the return value from `generate_game` is an `Array`, and that you don't care what is contained in each sub-array?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to turn the code you see above into a one-liner. The commented-out version is just an attempt. Looking back, I see that it should be reversed, I'll take care of that right now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use RSpec's [type matchers](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/type-check-matchers).

This will work for your example:

`expect(generate_game).to be_a_kind_of Array`

Comment: Thank you, @Kenrick Chien. But how do I specifically require a nested array, 3 values of 3 subvalues each?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method to do that. However, you could make a custom RSpec matcher.